# Добавление различных элементов в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cardview

Я хочу реализовать новостную ленту, в которой могут быть cardView элементы с различной разметкой. Все новости идут с сервера и предварительно не известно, какую позицию в коллекции будет занимать элемент. Можно ли это как-то сделать по String идентификатору, в котором пишется стиль новости?

Если нет, то как вообще это сделать в моем случае?

Вот пока что нагулил, что можно сделать так, но это по позиции.

```
  private class RecyclerViewHolderSimple extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   ...

    RecyclerViewHolderSimple(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ...

    }

    void bind(ModelItem modelItem) {

        ...
    }
}

private  class RecyclerViewHolderSmall extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ...

    RecyclerViewHolderSmall(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

       ...


    }

    void bind(ModelItem modelItem) {
        ...
    }
}

private class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ModelItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    void addAll(List<ModelItem> fakeItems) {
        int pos = getItemCount();
        this.items.addAll(fakeItems);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(pos, this.items.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if (position == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh=null;
        View itemLayoutView;

        switch (getItemViewType(viewType))
        {
            case 0:
                itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card_news, parent, false);
                vh = new RecyclerViewHolderSimple(itemLayoutView);
                break;
            case 1:
                itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card_small_news, parent, false);
                vh = new RecyclerViewHolderSmall(itemLayoutView);
                break;
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (this.getItemViewType(position))
        {
            case 0:
                RecyclerViewHolderSimple simple = (RecyclerViewHolderSimple) holder;
                simple.bind(items.get(position));
                break;
            case 1:
                RecyclerViewHolderSmall small = (RecyclerViewHolderSmall) holder;
                small.bind(items.get(position));
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

}
```

И вот соответственно добавление элементов в коллекцию:

```
 //В переменную news данные идут с Get запроса через retrofit 2.0

 String arrayNews[] = new String[news.size()] //Вот здесь я хотел хранить типы новостей, чтобы потом сравнивать и вставлять нужную разметку, но нет, кек

 for (int i = news.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (news.get(i).getType().equals("simple")) {
                    itemsList.add(new ModelItem(news.get(i).getAuthor(), news.get(i).getUrlToImage(), news.get(i).getTitle(), news.get(i).getContent(), i, Integer.valueOf(news.get(i).getLikes())));
                    arrayNews[news.size()-i]="simple";
                }
                else {
                    itemsList.add(new ModelItem(news.get(i).getTitle()));
                    arrayNews[news.size()-i]="small";
                }
            }
```

Comment: У вас как приходят данные для CardView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тип элемента определяется по позиции, да.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    ModelItem item = itemsList.get(position);
    switch (item.getType()){
        case "simple": return 0;
        default: return 1;
    }
}
```

ЗЫ. У вас опечатка в `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
switch (getItemViewType(viewType))
```

надо

```
switch (viewType)
```